# How to rotate Pyramid chart in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I was trying to rotate or flip Pyramid chart to show upside down(reverse pyramid) in SSRS 2012.

Any idea how to do it.

I Just want to flip below graph to show as reverse pyramid in SSRS.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: You could use the [Funnel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220409(v=sql.110).aspx) chart.

Comment: @UweAllner : added image as it is pointing up but I need to show such that it would point down. Flip it